# conditional ng-content in angular 4/5

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

Hi I want some conditional implementation of **ng-content**
e.g.

```
<div>
   <ng-content select="[card-icon]"></ng-content>
</div>
<div  #body>
   <div *ngIf="description.children.length;else newDiv">
      <ng-content select="[card-body]"></ng-content>
   </div>
   <div #newDiv>
      <ng-content select="[card-body]"></ng-content>
   </div>
</div>
<div  style="align-self: end;" #description [ngClass]="{'hide':!(description.children.length)}">
<ng-content select="[card-description]" ></ng-content>
</div>
```

but nothing is projected in the #newDiv.
TIA.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use given snippet:

```
 <div *ngIf=description.children.length>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tempOutlet" ></ng-container>
 </div>
 <div *ngIf=!description.children.length>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tempOutlet" ></ng-container>
 </div>
 <ng-template #tempOutlet>
     <ng-content select="[card-body]"></ng-content>
 </ng-template>
```

**Explanation**: This is done because if you have multiple ng-content of same types (e.g. card-body, card-icon or blank) then the last ng-content in your template will be added to your HTML. So have a single ng-content and make it project into multiple positions using ng-template and template outlet.

Comment: not working for me and I have actually found an issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948301/using-ng-content-in-ng-template

Answer (score 5):

Better make use of `ng-template`

```
   <div *ngIf="description.children.length;else newDiv">
      <ng-content select="[card-body]"></ng-content>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="newDiv"></ng-container>
   </div>

   <ng-template #newDiv>
      <ng-content select="[card-body]"></ng-content>
   </ng-template>
```

Comment: Why ? will you please explain ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi this will clear your doubts i hope https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Comment: nothing happen @RahulSingh i think  <ng-content select="[card-body]"></ng-content> should be at single place only i.e. should not be duplicated