# Accessing child data in parent using <ng-content>

Tags: angular

I'm trying  to include some template in child from parent, but I need to access child properties inside tranclusions.
Is there any way to do so ?

Child Component:-

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of companies">
    {{item.name}} <ng-content></ng-content>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Parent Component:-

```
<app-child [companies]="companies">
  <a href="">
    Visit {{item}}
  </a>
</app-child>
```

I need "item" inside my parent component here.

Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fj94ej

Comment: its possible with ng-template. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948301/using-ng-content-in-ng-template

Comment: Thanks @enno.void! Can you change the mentioned stackblitz and make it work using <ng-template> ?